# Parallel For losing values when looping

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I'm facing a strange issue that I can't explain and I would like to know if some of you have the answer I'm lacking.

I have a small test app for testing multithreading modifications I'm making to a much larger code. In this app I've set up two functions, one that does a loop sequentially and one that uses the Task.Parallel.For . The two of them print out the time and final elements generated. What I'm seeing is that the function that executes the Parallel.For is generating less items than the sequential loop and this is huge problem for the real app(it's messing with some final results). So, my question is if someone has any idea why this could be happening and if so, if there's anyway to fix it.

Here is the code for the function that uses the parallel.for in my test app:

```
static bool[] values = new bool[52];

static List<int[]> combinations = new List<int[]>();

static void ParallelLoop()
{
    combinations.Clear();
    Parallel.For(0, 48, i =>
    {
        if (values[i])
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < 49; j++)
                if (values[j])
                {

                    for (int k = j + 1; k < 50; k++)
                    {

                        if (values[k])
                        {

                            for (int l = k + 1; l < 51; l++)
                            {
                                if (values[l])
                                {
                                    for (int m = l + 1; m < 52; m++)
                                    {
                                        if (values[m])
                                        {
                                            int[] combination = { i, j, k, l, m };
                                            combinations.Add(combination);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }

    }); // Parallel.For
}
```

And here is the app output:

```
Executing sequential loop...
Number of elements generated: 1,712,304
Executing parallel loop...
Number of elements generated: 1,464,871
```

Thanks in advance and if you need some clarifications I'll do my best to explain in further detail.

Comment: Can't tell if trolling or honestly can't read the `Thread Safety` section of MSDN...

Comment: Just beside ken2k's Answer which is absolutely correct to my mind; parallel execution containing such for-loops would by trend be slower then a sequential execution. Working with huge lists will make the required locking ("Thread safety") much slower.

Comment: You must be a Lisp fan :-)

Comment: I've already noticed that the linear execution is faster than the parallel one but I'm just curious why the heck this was happening. I had read about Thread Safety but I didn't have a lot of time to do proper and extensive research on the matter as I was working on a really tight schedule.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't just add items in your list by multiple threads at the same time without any synchronization mechanism. `List<T>.Add()` actually does some none-trivial internal stuff (buffers...etc) so adding an item is **not** an atomic thread-safe operation.

Either:

- Provide a way to synchronize your writes
- Use a collection that supports concurrent writes (see `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace)
- Don't use multi-threading at all

Comment: Thanks, I figured it had something to do with the whole multi tread thing, but couldn't really point it. I'm not going to use multi-thread as it runs much slower in the end, but this problem was bugging me anyway. It's good to learn about the mistakes I make when I code! Thank you very much!